# Bullet stays in place but I want it to move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to program an enemy who is following my player and shooting at it. The player following part works, but when it shoots the bullets stay in place. Bullet has a Collider which is set to trigger. And the Player has tag - Player assigned to it
Here is the script for the bullet:

```
public float speed;
  private Transform player;
  private Vector2 target;

void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        target = new Vector2(player.position.x, player.position.y);
    }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Move projectile towards
    //Ja gribam lai lode seko transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    if(transform.position.x == target.x && transform.position.y == target.y){
        DestroyProjectile();
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
   if(other.CompareTag("Player")){
       DestroyProjectile();
}
}
void DestroyProjectile(){
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

}

And here is the script for the enemy:

```
public float speed;
public float stoppingDistance;
public float retreatDistance;
private float timeBtwShots;
public float startTimeBtwShots;
public GameObject projectile;
public Transform player;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Checking distance between enemies
    if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > stoppingDistance)
    {
        //Move enemy towards player
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    //Check if the distance is smaller and make sure if enemy isnt too near to the player
    } else if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < stoppingDistance && Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > retreatDistance){
        //Too near enemy will stop moving
        transform.position = this.transform.position;
    //if distance is smaller than retreat Back away
    } else if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) < retreatDistance){

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, -speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    // Shootig
    if(timeBtwShots <= 0){
        Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;
    } else {
        timeBtwShots -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In general when using physics you shouldn't move your objects via `Transform` at all since this might break physics and collision detection. Then you could also simply give the bullet a `Rigidbody2D` and a certain forwards velocity and when you instantiate it simply make it point at the player -> it will automatically move in that direction

Answer (score 0):

The code itself has no problems, so it must be an issue with something else.

One possibility is that `GameObject projectile` might not be set in the unity inspector. The projectile should also have a bullet component on it, so make sure that is correct.

The cause could also be the bullet speed. By default, it is set to 0 and if it is, it wont move. Double check the value in the inspector to make sure it isn't 0.

A third possibility is that there could be multiple objects with the player tag, causing FindGameObjectWithTag to return the wrong player object. It is unlikely but would be fixed by using a different method of getting the player object such as setting it in the enemy script